# Add separate component to Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have to add some component(comments for example) to my app:
I'm trying:

in comment.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'am-comments',
    template: `<h4>{{title}}</h4>`
})

export class CommentComponent {
    title = 'Comments title';
}
```

my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { CommentComponent } from './comment.component'; <--

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CommentComponent // <--
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

finally in output :

```
<am-comments>Waiting...</am-comments>
```

But it doesn't output template from CommentComponent outsite parent component

What I've missed?

Dir structure very simple:

[image]

Comment: You need to import the module that contains `CommentComponent` to modules where you use it. Is `<am-comments>Waiting...</am-comments>` in `AppModule` or another module?

Comment: I need to create separate component, but with this approach I can create only child component.
For example in parent component template: template: `<h1>somehtml</h1><am-comments>here will be child comment component</am-comments>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you try to rephrase? What do you mean by "can create only child component" and what do you mean by "doesn't output template from CommentComponent outside parent component"?

Comment: I can declare my comments dirrective only in parent template 
http://prnt.sc/cbc4mo

Comment: Seems you mean "use" (instead of "declare"). Where else do you want to use it?

Comment: What do you mean "Where?" Where I need It - in any part of html page.
Outside parent component

Comment: You can't add Angular2 components or directives outside the root component. You can only bootstrap components outside the root component.

Comment: Thank you, It's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 components and directives can't be used directly outside a root component. They can only be used within the template of another component.

The only way is to bootstrap different modules as additional Angular2 applications, where each bootstrapped module has a different component registered for `bootstrap: [ XxxComponent ]`.

Directives and pipes can't be used outside the root component at all.

Currently the root components of each bootstrapped module need to have a different selector. This is planned to be changed in the future.